# Understanding Bigquery caching for views

Tags: google-cloud-platform, caching, google-bigquery, database-view, database-caching

In BQ, if we are querying from the view `z` which is say for example `select * from x join y` and we want to do:

`select a from z where <where_clause>`
and
`select b from z where <where_clause_2>`

Will the results of the view `z` be cached?

i.e. Under the hood,

Is it

`select a from z where <where_clause>` = `select a from x join y where <where_clause>`
(where x join y is cached for the next query)

and
`select b from z` = `select b from z' where <where_clause_2>`
(where z' is cached z) [NOTE]

OR

will it be
`select a from z` = `select a from x join y where where_clause_2`
and
`select b from z` =  `select b from x join y where where_clause_2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#limitations), the cache applies with the exact same request.

Here, you reuse a part of a request and the cache does not apply on the part of request.